# In server side can I take location by mobile devices in web asp net site (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, geolocation

I know that with javascript, I can use the

```
navigate.geolocation
```

But what about the serverside?
How can I see the location still in the controller? Because otherwise I will have to rewrite the whole application to return the data by json

Comment: you'd have to send the location data to the server in your request. Obviously the server does not know where the client is. All it gets is the request data, nothing more.

Comment: @ADyson Exactly. I was looking for method in Request object could let me know that. But I see that this does not exist

Comment: A HTTP request can contain any data you like. It's up to you to supply it in whatever format is suitable, e.g. url-encoded, JSON, XML etc.

Comment: You mean in a POST, right? But how I do this in the default page access. I do not know if I am clear ... My site has an option where the user can select a city to see the content related to that city. All in MVC, just using C # with post and reloading the page. And I'm trying to figure out how to deliver the content of the user's city, without him having to choose that city and reload the page.

Comment: or in a GET, by passing values on the querystring, or in a PUT or DELETE, it doesn't matter. So...when the page loads, ask the user for their location, if they give it to you, put that in a JS variable, send that value to the server using AJAX and get the result for the relevant city. If they don't grant you permission to get the location, ask them to type in a location instead, and then send that data to your server instead. Once you've got the location data (which is just a set of co-ordinates), it's no different to sending any other kind of data to the server.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation shows you how to get the data as a JS variable. If you need to know how to run JS code immediately when the page loads, well it's very easy to google that, lots of examples. P.S. If you don't want to use AJAX, then just put the co-ordinates into hidden fields on a form, and then submit the form (you can automate that using JS as well if you like) to cause a normal postback.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson